# iPod Touch - Infrared

Tags: ipod-touch, photos

Family has a new iPod Touch for christmas... and their pictures are showing up as what sounds like infrared.

I can't find documentation of a feature like that. We are fairly sure their haven't been any apps downloaded. I have an iPhone 4S and don't see anything like that, but things could be different on the Touch.

Does anyone know of "stock" features on the iPod Touch that allows for different camera features? Infrared, reverse black/white, etc?

PS: I don't have the touch in front of me and family isn't super computer savy... so help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not a built-in feature.  That's either an app that was installed or a camera defect.